# Laravel: How can I get latitude and longitude point from city name?

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5

I wanna get latitude and longitude point from city name, so that i can perform search on google map.

Answer (score 1):

This process is called [geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple). You can read on how to do it from the documentation. In short, you pass and address and you would get the coordinates.